# What's wrong with this DFS implementation?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I'm not sure what's wrong with the following depth-first-search code. The expected vs program output is included at the end. I obtained the expected output by running code from geeksforgeeks (s/o to them). Any help would be appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self._chdrn = []

class Nary:

    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self._n = n
        self._root = None

    def insert(self, val: int):
        nn = Node(val)
        if not self._root:
            self._root = nn
        else:
            def recur(parent: Node):
                print("Parent: ", parent._val)
                if len(parent._chdrn) < self._n:
                    parent._chdrn.append(nn)
                    return 1
                else:
                    for chdl in parent._chdrn:
                        ret = recur(chdl)
                        if ret == 1:
                            break
            parent = self._root
            recur(parent)

    def dfs(self):
        def _dfs(node: Node):
            if not node: return
            print(node._val, end=' ')
            for chld in node._chdrn:
                # print("current child = ", chld._val)
                _dfs(chld)
        _dfs(self._root)

Tree  = Nary(3)
for i in range(10): Tree.insert(i)
Tree.dfs()
```

#

Expected output: 0 1 4 5 6 2 7 8 9 3
Program output: 0 1 4 7 8 9 5 6 2 7 8 9 3

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wring with your DFS code. Your tree construction with the `insert` method is wrong.

You need to return in the recursive case when looping through children in `recur`. Otherwise the same node will get inserted under multiple parents.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self._chdrn = []


class Nary:

    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self._n = n
        self._root = None

    def insert(self, val: int):
        print(f"Inserting {val}")
        nn = Node(val)
        if not self._root:
            self._root = nn
        else:
            def recur(parent: Node):
                if len(parent._chdrn) < self._n:
                    print(f"Added under parent: {parent._val}")
                    parent._chdrn.append(nn)
                    return 1
                else:
                    for chdl in parent._chdrn:
                        ret = recur(chdl)
                        if ret == 1:
                            return 1  # not just break

            parent = self._root
            recur(parent)

    def dfs(self):
        def _dfs(node: Node):
            if not node: return
            print(node._val, end=' ')
            for chld in node._chdrn:
                # print("current child = ", chld._val)
                _dfs(chld)

        _dfs(self._root)


Tree = Nary(3)
for i in range(10): Tree.insert(i)
Tree.dfs()
```

BTW the correct DFS order for this tree is:

```
0 1 4 7 8 9 5 6 2 3
```

You should draw out the tree and manually do a DFS to verify.